# Explanation of html rendering for tables recursively

Tags: html, css

Can anybody explain the behaviour of the following html page, which is an extract of a legacy application?

My question is: between "My sample text here T1" and "My sample text here T2", the rendering is totally different, and the only difference is that there is a parent table around the second one.

My understanding of html is that table is a block level element that computes its width depending on the content, and I do not understand why there is a such difference in the rendering of this sample.

If anybody knows why and this behaviour can be controlled without forcing the width or using `white-space:nowrap`, I would be really thankful.

The code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- rendering is correct --> 
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 30%">&nbsp;</td>
                <td style="width: 35%">My sample text here T1</td>
                <td style="width: 35%">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>


<!-- Problem is here : addition of a parent table. -->
<table><tr><td>

    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 30%">&nbsp;</td>
                <td style="width: 35%">My sample text here T2</td>
                <td style="width: 35%">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</td></tr></table>


</body>
</html>
```

And the rendering :

[image]

Comment: Add the border=1 to each table element so that you can actually see what the tables are doing.

Comment: table shrinks on its content, if nested, inline content might shrink too since parent has no width specified for child to use

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that the outer td in T2 does not explicitly know its width and neither table, tr, nor td are block elements.  See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fordareh/u6j64tso/

Basically, you need the outer table to have an explicit width:

```
<table style="width: 100%"><tr><td>

    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 30%">&nbsp;</td>
                <td style="width: 35%">My sample text here T2</td>
                <td style="width: 35%">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</td></tr></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

table shrinks on its content, if nested, inline content might shrink too since parent has no width specified for child to use.

you may remove width style and maybe use a block element so it can receive `width`, `min-width`, `max-width` without interfering with the table layout.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- rendering is correct --> 
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 30%">&nbsp;</td>
                <td style="width: 35%">My sample text here T1</td>
                <td style="width: 35%">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>


<!--  addition of a parent table. -->
<table><tr><td>

    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>My sample text here T2</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</td></tr></table>

<!--  addition of a parent table. -->
<table><tr><td>

    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td><p>My sample text here T3</p></td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</td></tr></table>
</body>
</html>
```